# Python not recognized in Terminal

Tags: python-3.x, installation

so I just installed Python on a WIN10 Laptop, unfortunately, when checking via the Terminal with python --version I get the error message:
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any Idea what this could be related too?

Thanks!

Comment: i think python is not correctly installed on windows [read](https://edu.google.com/openonline/course-builder/docs/1.10/set-up-course-builder/check-for-python.html)

Comment: I downloaded it from the Python Homepage and the executable added it to the system and can find the file itself too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add python to your PATH environment variable.

Check this blog here : https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/